# IN in statement DB2 equivalence to HSQLDB

Tags: db2, hsqldb, ddl

I'm trying to change the code of a script .DDL of the database DB2 to HSQLDB, I have the problem next:

> Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Unexpected token: IN in statement [IN]

In a create table:

```
CREATE TABLE "tableName" (...) IN "USERSPACE1";
```

The statement IN don't exist in HSQLDB, are there any equivalence?

Comment: HSQLDB not support tablespaces nor any identical concept. So the statement IN don't exist in HSQLDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HSQLDB not support tablespaces nor any identical concept

Answer (score 0):

Each database system has its own persistence configuration methods and different keywords and DDL statements to access those methods. The `IN <table_space>` clause is for DB2 only.

To convert to HSQLDB, you can remove the clause. You can define the type of HSQLDB table persistence as MEMORY, CACHED, or TEXT (for CSV files). A separate statement can be used after the CREATE TABLE statement if the type of table you require is not the default. You can also change the default. Examples below:

```
SET DATABASE DEFAULT TABLE TYPE CACHED

SET TABLE <table name> TYPE CACHED
```